# Amazon S3 - Unsafe file types?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an application that allows users to upload content to Amazon S3. I was curious if there are certain file types I should be black listing for security reasons?

Would an .exe or any other runnable file be able to compromise my service or user's personal data?

I would guess there would be no way for any uploaded file to actually run, but I wanted to make sure before uploading the flood gates.

Comment: You should be aware of IP Related Risks. eg Unauthorized uploading of copyrighted MP3 files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing should be able to compromise your service *assuming it is written properly*.  if your concern is that user's data will be corrupted while stored on S3, no, that shouldn't be possible.  S3 is basically a network storage device.  It can't *execute* anything.

Basically, if you treat the files as chunks of data, and never execute or interpret the data in any way, you should be fine.  I'd be more worried about the more "standard" ways a web service might be vulnerable.

I should add, just to cover myself, that without knowing the details of what you are doing, it is impossible to answer your question with 100% certainty.